# Proof claimed of Gauss' Circle Problem

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, lattices

I just wanted to ask wether this problem has already been proved or not.

I know that there are 2 other posts that deal with exactly the same question, but I decided to ask it again, since they are too old (more than 5 years) and a new paper was published in 2015 on arxiv:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.02890

In spite that it's title contains the word *revised*, it does not seem to have been published. No "new mathematic" is presented, since it is a short paper. Any idea about it?

(Please, do not report this question as "duplicate", since we are working with new information that was not available years ago)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Gauss circle problem is open (as of now).